# Failing to convert a string to int in c++

Tags: c++, string

I started learning C++ few days abck and I have been working on a sample project where I need to convert a string to int. I am facing an issue in the following code:

```
#include <string>
#include <stdlib.h>

string sIMX = "45250";
int IMXValue = atoi(sIMX);
int IMXDeg = IMXValue/10;   
string sIMXFinal = std::to_string(IMXDeg);
strcpy(sIMX, sIMXFinal);
cout<<"String Value = "<<sIMX;
```

I have to convert a value present in string to an integer... divide it by 10 and then store the value in a string and display it.

Error: 'to_string' is not a member of 'std'

Comment: How are you compiling it? `std::to_string` is new in c++11, you will need the `-std=c++11` in your make command.

Comment: first, use `<cstdlib>` if you're in c++. Secondly `atoi` takes a `const char*` argument not an `std::string` one, use `stoi`.

Comment: @Ben: I am using a linux compiler.

Comment: `strcpy(sIMX, sIMXFinal);` should not compile. `strcpy` doesn't take `std::string` (unless its your function with the same name as in the standard library).

Comment: @MikePortnoy He didn't ask what platform, he asked how. But you saying that probably means you're using `g++` which would definitely require you to pass `-std=c++11` as a compile parameter.

Comment: @MikePortnoy you should get a lot of compiler errors for this code (other than the to_string one).

Comment: @CoffeeandCode some platforms g++ -std=c++11 still does not have `to_string` (e.g. Cygwin)

Comment: @MattMcNabb then they shouldn't have that flag at all. IIRC `-std=c++0x` is the flag when the compiler doesn't have **full** c++11 support

Comment: instead of `atoi`, use C++11 `stoi`. the C level `atoi` doesn't take a `std::string` as argument and lacks failure reporting. using `stdlib.h` is OK and is preferred, when one needs that header, but you don't need it: just remove that include. the error you get *can* be due to not specifying `-std=c++11`. it *can* alternatively be due to using an old compiler version that doesn't support C++11 stuff.

Comment: Is this question about `int` to `string` or `string` to `int` ?

Comment: oh, and instead of `strcpy`, just use ordinary `=` *assignment* for `std::string`. or use *initialization*. which can look like an assignment.

Comment: @user3477950 I didn't mention linux, did you mean to tag someone else?

Comment: @MattMcNabb Aw, sorry, yes. Of course that was directed to OP.

Comment: @MikePortnoy The answer to "how" is not "linux". BTW, "a linux compiler" is not helpful (also, there's in fact no such thing as a "linux compiler".)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I think you are hopefully using c++11 in which case you should do this:

```
#include <string>
using namespace std;

string sIMX = "45250";
int IMXValue = stoi(sIMX);
int IMXDeg = IMXValue/10;   
string sIMXFinal = to_string(IMXDeg);
cout << "String Value = " <<sIMXFinal;
```

and if you wanted to be clever:

```
string sIMX = "45250";
string sIMXFinal = to_string(stoi(sIMX)/10);
```

this is all c++ stuff and should make your life a little easier. You could also use `stringstreams`. Dont forget to compile with:

```
g++ -std=c++11 yourprogram.cpp -o outputname
```

Comment: @Nawaz are you saying my answer is good or bad? Do you have some suggestions.

Comment: @Ben: It is good, and I upvoted it. I asked Mike to upvote it as well You deserve 25 points from Mike, not only 15 points. ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Your approach is quizzical as the recommended way of converting strings to integers is **using a stringstream**

```
std::string number = "123456789";

std::stringstream ss(number);

int num = 0;

ss >> num;

if (ss.fail()) {
    // Error
}
else {
    std::cout << "The integer value is: " << num;
}
```

Requires: `<sstream>`

Comment: re " the recommended way of converting strings to integers is using a stringstream", recommended by whom, in what context?

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf: AFAIK: from a number of SO posts if using C++ streams. For C-style strings, that's a different story.

Comment: well you can forget that advice. what to use depends very much on the context, but with `stoi` being the simplest way, most clear code and least to type, and therefore generally preferred. SO is simply not a good authority on anything. by the way, where you do need a narrow output stringsstream, use `std::ostringstream` to avoid bringing in baggage you don't need. and to be clear about intent, and where you do need a narrow input stringstream, use `std::istringstream` (same rationale).

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf: I agree with you on the part with SO not being an authority, and to an extent with `stoi` being clear and perhaps the easiest. But, as usage of either method depends on the context - the likes of which aren't fully stated in the OP's question - IMO, the most general solution would be to use a `stringstream`: hence my post. Nonetheless, thank you for your comments! :)

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using atoi already, you could use itoa to convert in the opposite direction.

Comment: Note that [`itoa` is not a standard C function](http://www.delorie.com/djgpp/doc/libc/libc_517.html), but [is a Posix function](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/atoi.html).